# What is the best way to handle multiple range input sliders in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, input, range, slider

I am working on a web page that has multiple (8) input sliders on the same page.  I found a script that works for one slider using document.getElementById.  Since I'll need ID's for all 8 sliders, I'm not sure how to alter this code to accommodate all 8.

Bottom line, is there a way to have multiple ID's in the same script?

Here's my html:

```
<div class="range-wrap"> 
  <input id="range" type="range" name="range" min="3" max="20" value="12" step="1" class="slider">
  <p id="display" style="text-align:center;margin-top:30px;"></p>
  <p id="numVal" style="text-align:center;color:#f1f1f1;"></p> 
</div>
```

Here's my JavaScript:

```
 var slider = document.getElementById("range");
var display = document.getElementById("display");
var getVal = slider.value;

numVal.innerHTML = getVal; // If you don't want the number to be displayed, delete this. This is to show at which number the label will change

if(getVal<7) {
  display.innerHTML = "Need Help";
}

if(getVal>=7 && getVal<=15) {
  display.innerHTML = "Mediocre";
}

if(getVal>20){
  display.innerHTML = "Doing Great";
}

slider.oninput = function() {
  numVal.innerHTML = this.value;// If you don't want the number to be displayed, delete this. This is to show at which number the label will change
  
  var getVal = this.value;
  if(getVal<5) {
    display.innerHTML = "Need Help";
  }
  
  if(getVal>=7 && getVal<=10) {
    display.innerHTML = "Mediocre";
  }
  
  if(getVal>15){
    display.innerHTML = "Doing Great";
  }
}
```

I tried changing getElementById to getElementsByClassName and assigning each element a class, but it broke the script.

I am not an experienced JS coder.

Comment: why are you duplicating the if statements? If you find yourself copy and pasting things that is a good sign for code smell. Put it into a function and call it OR trigger the event of the listener.

Answer (score 0):

To handle multiple sliders on the same page, you can use classes instead of IDs:

```js
<div class="range-wrap">
  <input class="slider" type="range" name="range" min="3" max="20" value="12" step="1">
  <p class="display" style="text-align:center;margin-top:30px;"></p>
  <p class="numVal" style="text-align:center;color:#f1f1f1;"></p> 
</div>
```

Afterwards, you can access all `input` elements with class `slider` by using [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName):

```js
const sliders = document.getElementsByClassName("slider");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.querySelectorAll` to select all the sliders on the page and then loop through them to add event listeners. Here’s an example of how you could do it:

```js
var sliders = document.querySelectorAll(".slider");
  
sliders.forEach(function(slider) {
  var display = document.getElementById("display" + slider.id.slice(-1));
  var numVal = document.getElementById("numVal" + slider.id.slice(-1));

  slider.oninput = function() {
    numVal.innerHTML = this.value;
    var getVal = this.value;
    if(getVal<5) { display.innerHTML = "Need Help"; }
    if(getVal>=7 && getVal<=10) { display.innerHTML = "Mediocre"; }
    if(getVal>15){ display.innerHTML = "Doing Great"; }
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="range-wrap">
  <input id="range1" type="range" name="range" min="3" max="20" value="12" step="1" class="slider">
  <p id="display1" style="text-align:center;margin-top:30px;"></p>
  <p id="numVal1" style="text-align:center;color:#f1f1f1;"></p>
</div>
<div class="range-wrap">
  <input id="range2" type="range" name="range" min="3" max="20" value="12" step="1" class="slider">
  <p id="display2" style="text-align:center;margin-top:30px;"></p>
  <p id="numVal2" style="text-align:center;color:#f1f1f1;"></p>
</div>
<!-- Add more sliders here -->
```

This way, you can have multiple sliders on the same page and update their displays independently without having to write separate code for each slider.